# How to verify a table column values only contains subset of another table column values?

Tags: sql, oracle

suppose there is two table called table1 and table2 as follows,

table1

```
id | val1
--------
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
```

table2

```
id | val2
----------
1   2
2   4
3   5
```

How to verify by using oracle sql, table2.val2 column contains only subset of table1.val1 values.

How about this solution,

```
select * from table2 where val2 not in (select val1 from table1);
```

If above query return any result, then val2 column is not subset of a val1. If not it is a subsuet of val1.

is there any alternative way to do this better and shorter than this solution?

Comment: take right join between val1 and val2 and ensure there are no NULLs

Comment: With constraints to enforce referential integrity?

Comment: suppose there is no val2 values which is not found in val1 column. But im not sure about that. so I want to verify that.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `NOT EXISTS` to find `table2.val2` that are not in `table1.val1` like this

```
SELECT *
FROM table2 t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT 1
  FROM table1 t1
  WHERE t1.val1 = t2.val2
)
```

and if it returns an empty result then `table2.val2` is a subset of `table1.val1`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming ID is not nullable, I think this is the simplest query that will give you all the records in table2
where Val2 can't be found in Table1.Val1:

```
SELECT t2.Id, t2.Val2
FROM Table2 t2
LEFT JOIN Table1 t1 ON t2.Val2 = t1.Val1
WHERE t1.Id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

The way that you guarantee this is by creating a foreign key constraint.  Assuming that `table1.id` is the primary key, you can add one as:

```
alter table table2 add constraint fk_table2_val2
    foreign key (val2) references table1(val1);
```

`val1` should be declared as unique in the table.

Before doing this, you need to do something about `val2` values that might be incorrect.  It is unclear what you want to do about these:

- Set such `val2` values to `NULL`.
- Set such `val2` values to a "canonical" value.
- Add such `val2` values to `table1`.
- Delete rows with such `val2` values.

Without guidance on what to do, it is hard to make a concrete proposal.

Comment: I think your answer should be changed as table1(val1) instead of table1(id)

Answer (score 0):

You may try this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
    SELECT
        t2.id as t2_id,
        t2.val2,
        t1.id as t1_id,
        t1.val1
    FROM
        table2 t2 LEFT JOIN table1 t1
            ON t2.val2 = t1.val1
) a

WHERE a.t1_id IS NULL;
```

If this gives `no records`, it means table2.val2 contains only subset of table1.val1 values.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table2 where val2 not in (select val1 from table1);
```

If above query return any result, then val2 column is not subset of a val1. If not it is a subsuet of val1.